# c# Linq count group by

Tags: c#

My getTrustActivitiesFromStorage List looks something this

```
venueId     venueName     activityId
1           Location1     Zumba
2           Location2     Yoga
1           Location1     Yoga
1           Location1     MetaFit
3           Location3     Zumba
```

Here's the code i use to group etc

```
List<TrustActivities> filteredVenues = new List<TrustActivities>();

IEnumerable<TrustActivities> groupedVenueCollection = getTrustActivitiesFromStorage
    .GroupBy(customer => customer.venueName)
    .Select(group => group.First())
    .OrderBy(x => x.venueName);

    // Loop
    foreach (TrustActivities activity in groupedVenueCollection)
    {
        filteredVenues.Add(new TrustActivities 
        { 
            filterId = Convert.ToInt32(activity.venueId), 
            filterName = activity.venueName,
            filterCount = 55
        });
    }
```

This successfully groups the list and outputs the 3 matches:

- 1 Location1 (55)
  2 Location2 (55)
  3 Location3 (55)

The final bit i need help with is counting each group, so filterCount = 55 will be replace with the dynamic count to give:

- 1 Location1 (3)
  2 Location2 (1)
  3 Location3 (1)

can someone show me how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need `group.Count()`:

```
var groupedVenueCollection = getTrustActivitiesFromStorage
    .GroupBy(customer => customer.venueName)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key);

foreach (var group in groupedVenueCollection)
{
    TrustActivities firstActivity = group.First();
    filteredVenues.Add(new TrustActivities 
    { 
        filterId = Convert.ToInt32(firstActivity.venueId), 
        filterName = firstActivity.venueName,  // or group.Key
        filterCount = group.Count()  // <--- !!!
    });
}
```

You could also do it in one query without a loop:

```
List<TrustActivities> filteredVenues = getTrustActivitiesFromStorage
 .GroupBy(customer => customer.venueName)
 .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
 .Select(g => new { Activity = g.First(), Count = g.Count() })
 .Select(x => new TrustActivities 
    { 
        filterId = Convert.ToInt32(x.Activity.venueId), 
        filterName = x.Activity.venueName,
        filterCount = x.Count
    })
.ToList();
```

Comment: @Scott: Have you noticed that i've also provided a way to do it one query without a loop?

Comment: yes that is neat, although i had to change Count = group.Count()  to Count = g.Count() and it worked perfect too! thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `.Select(g => g.First())`, you'd do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<TrustActivities> groupedVenueCollection = getTrustActivitiesFromStorage
    .GroupBy(customer => new { customer.venueId, customer.venueName });

foreach (var activity in groupedVenueCollection)
{
    filteredVenues.Add(new TrustActivities 
    { 
        filterId = Convert.ToInt32(activity.Key.venueId), 
        filterName = activity.Key.venueName,
        filterCount = activity.Count()
    });
}
```

Also, your variable names are confusing. The table appears to be venues, but you call them customers and activities